# How to let the user choose the background color

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's say that I want a user to change the background color of the app. I was thinking about creating several xml layout files and then have a ListView with the list of the layout files. Then, when the user selects one of those, the corresponding xml file would be loaded.

Is this possible? If yes, how should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple way do it dynamic in code. Just save user color to SharedPreferences and use it in code as background for your Views.

So I suggest to use ColorPikerDialog to choose any color. You can use for example this library https://github.com/gsingh93/android-ColorPickerPreference

```
SharedPrefrences prefs = getSharedPrefrences(YOUR_SHARED_PREFS, 0);
int colorId = prefs.getInt(BACKGROUND_COLOR, 0);
if(colorId != 0) {
   setBackgroundToColorId(colorId);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Plese introduce me, what does "background color of the app" means?) If you want set special color as background color for any View you can use method setBackground(Color) for each view in your code. If you want set any drawable for your views I think you can try to make any Styles in xml and set style in depend on user choose.

Comment: I mean the `<color name="background">#133b96</color>` declared in `values/colors`. I would like the user to be able to change it by selecting it from a list and, doing so, changing it throughout the app.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I see this solution. Just use ColorPickerDialog. It's the best way to choose any color. When user choose color save it to SharedPreferenses. After that get this color everywhere and use method View.setBackgroundColor(Color). For me it's good solution.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but probably I haven't explained myself very well: this lets the user choose among any color, but what I would like to do is to have a list of styles (defined by me), and let the user choose among them. Example: I have a list with two items, Light and Dark. The first one has black text and white background, the second one is the opposite. The user should only be able to pick between the two.

Comment: You can get Application from any Actiivty and use method setTheme(YOUR_STYLE); About styles can read there http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html Just create new style and override standart Holo for example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22523/discussion-between-ilya-demidov-and-user1301428)

Answer (score 1):

I have already did this, When the user select a color from the listview track that colorid and save it in the share preferences as @llya Demidov said.

```
 editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    editor.putString(PREF_COLOR, <userselectedcolor>);
```

before loading each activity do like this

```
 pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            int color= pref.getString(PREF_COLOR, null);
    if(color!=0)
    {
    yourlayoutid.setbackgroundColor(Color);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this thing as the suggestion only,

You can put an edittext which take the color code of the color the user wants,With that you can use a TextWatcher as colors have hexadecimal values and each color has fix length of 6 alphanumeric character like "FF0000" ,as soon as the length goes to six the color will apply.

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) 
        {

            if(editable.toString().length==6)
                 //set color of background
        }
    });
}
```